# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, lodash

I have downloaded node-js and I am using npm inside a folder. I have downloaded the **lodash** package as a dependency and it is in the **node modules** folder.

but when I try to use it using **require()** it is giving above mentioned error in the console and suggesting to use **ES6 modul**e by vs code and require is a module of **common.js**

I have a package.json file and lodash is listed as a dependency. I am able to run lodash in the command line using node server but not in the browser

Do we need any other package installed in order for require() function to run other than **node-js**?
what am I doing wrong?
I am on windows and using the latest version of node and npm
    let a = require('lodash');

Comment: do u have a package.json file

Comment: yes, I have a package.json file and lodash is listed as a dependency.
I am able to run lodash in the command line but not in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

If VSCode is suggesting you use ES6 modules, then you may have turned on ES6 Module support in your project which overrides Node's default support for CommonJS modules.

Use

```
import lodash from 'lodash';
```

instead of require.

---

Re edit:

> I am able to run lodash in the command line using node server but not in the browser

Well yes. If you run a program designed to work in Node.js in Node.js then it work. If you run the same program in a browser, then it won't work. Just having Node.js installed somewhere doesn't turn the browser into Node.js.

If you want to use an ES6 module in a browser then:

- It must be compatible with browsers (lodash *might* be)
- You need to use `import lodash from "./url/to/lodash.js";` because browsers don't have support for resolving npm paths.

If the module isn't designed to run in browsers, then you might be able to use a tool like Webpack to bundle it up in a way that will work (but that won't work in the module depends on APIs provided by Node.js, like `fs`).

Comment: not working.
import lodash from './node_modules/lodash'; is giving this error
Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

import lodash from 'lodash'; is giving this error - 
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "lodash". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Comment: @Husain — There shouldn't be a server. You said you were using Node.js. If you're using a web browser, then you aren't using Node.js.

Answer (score -1):

You can use express framework to work on NODE js

let express =  require('express') ;

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it.
Should I install Express using npm and use it?

Comment: yes you can use npm install express ..and require its functionalities